# Scroll using the keyboard?

Tags: sublimetext2

How can I scroll up and down a file using my keyboard? I tried the arrow keys plus different modifiers.

Comment: You can always [make keyboard shortcuts](http://superuser.com/a/298636/54873) to suit your needs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you look at the default key binding for the program (on Mac version, this is in the menu "Sublime Text 2/Preferences/Key Bindings - Default"), you can see what all the keyboard shortcuts are.

I did a find for "scroll" and found these lines:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+up"], "command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": 1.0} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+down"], "command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": -1.0} },
```

So, `ctrl+alt+up` and `ctrl+alt+down` will scroll the view up and down 1 line at a time. If you want to change this, copy these lines into your "Key Bindings - User" file and change the corresponding parts of the line.

Comment: Oh crap, you're right, on Windows it's `ctrl+up` but the plugin Emmet is overwriting them with some number incrementer. thanks

Comment: Thaks so much I have been looking for this for a long time. I set scroll lines to 3, it's default on mouse scroll I think.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar, you can always override it by using User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap

Comment: doesn't work for me on ST3 (OSX)... and I have the same bindings... nothing happens - any ideas?

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic I would look to see if another command from a plugin has the same bindings and is causing a conflict.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but where exactly to check that? I don't know how to see the list of all bindings across all plugins?

Comment: Anyone know how to make it scroll and also go to _n_ lines up/down depending the direction?

Comment: @davidhq Package [FindKeyConflicts](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts) can show you which keyboard shortcuts are bound to more than one command, or simply list every key binding you have.